# MediaRecorder Alternatives

Tags: javascript, mediarecorder, getusermedia

Ive been playing about with `MediaRecorder` to save a `MediaStream` that has been created by `getUserMedia`. I'm really happy with the results, however I need something similar that has better cross browser support.

Here is some sample code for how I'm using `MediaRecorder` (just to give you some context):

```
var mediaRec;
navigator.getUserMedia({
    audio:true
},function(stream){
    mediaRec=new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRec.start(10000);
    mediaRec.ondataavailable=function(e){

    };
},function(err){});
```

It seems that [`MediaRecorder` only works in the Firefox browser and the Firefox OS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder_API/Using_the_MediaRecorder_API).

However [`MediaRecorder` is part of the W3C Specification](http://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-record/MediaRecorder.html), and [Google Chrome has stated it intends to support it in a future release](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/2l_G_apqk30), but what options do I have in the meantime?

I know that plug ins such as Flash and Silverlight can achieve the same thing that `MediaRecorder` performs, but what I need is a javascript solution.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the other options that are available will be utilizing high-level APIs and implemented at the Browser/JavaScript level. Thus, none will really be comparable to the MediaRecorder API provided by Firefox as it is integrated into the browser and has the benefit of being "lower level" in the browser's implementation.

One option I know that works for sure(though utilizes the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API)) is [Matt Diamond's Recorderjs](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs).

And Example using Recorderjs taken from Matt's github.

```
  var audio_context;
  var recorder;

  function startUserMedia(stream) {
    var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

    input.connect(audio_context.destination);

    recorder = new Recorder(input);
  }

  function startRecording() {
    recorder.record();
  }

  function stopRecording(button) {
    recorder.stop();
    createDownloadLink();

    recorder.clear();
  }

  function createDownloadLink() {
    recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      var au = document.createElement('audio');
      var hf = document.createElement('a');

      au.controls = true;
      au.src = url;
      hf.href = url;
      hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
      hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
      li.appendChild(au);
      li.appendChild(hf);
      recordingslist.appendChild(li);
    });
  }

  window.onload = function init() {
    try {
      // webkit shim
      window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
      navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
      window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

      audio_context = new AudioContext;

    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, startUserMedia, function(e) {
      console.log('No live audio input: ' + e);
    });
```